# ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

> `ErrorException` in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 135:
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

What would be causing me to get the above error?  I do have a custom middleware.

I am not sure what files to post as it happens when I login and in my  view I have

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

**Routes:**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {

    /* Admin Auth */
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.admin'], function(){
    /*Admin Dashboard Routes */
        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@getDashboard');
        Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@getDashboard');    
    });
});



Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

**Middleware:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminAuthController
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if(Auth::guard($guard)->guest())
        {
            if ($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }else{
                return redirect()->guest('admin/login');
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Comment: @JilsonThomas Done

Comment: In what page are you getting this error?

Comment: @JilsonThomas /admin/dashboard do you want the middleware too?

Comment: yes, please post it too

Comment: @JilsonThomas Done

Comment: Your logical branching doesn't return on all paths, so you can end up with a null being returned to the pipeline. There has to be a response returned, since the previous middleware will then handle that response and so on.

Comment: @lagbox What do I have to do to resolve? and can you explain a bit more

Comment: Middleware have to return responses. You are potentially returning a `null` since your `if` block is the only thing returning anything. So if that is false you are returning null. Then that response (or lack of one) makes it to the csrf middleware which is expecting a response object to add something to.

Comment: Also you are not allowing the response to continue through the middleware stack as `return $next($request);` is never called. That single line is what allows the request to continue moving through the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('admin/login');
    }
    // they are not a guest, so lets allow the request
    // to continue to the application
    return $next($request);
    // we are returning the response from where ever it started
    // from down the pipeline
}
```

If the request meets some criteria we are stopping it from continuing deeper into the application by not calling `$next($request)`. In either cases we end up returning a response that is some form of the `Response` class, hopefully.

The CSRF middleware is taking a request, examining it, and if it passes then it passes the request deeper into the application. This call returns a response which it would like to add a cookie too, but to do that it is expecting a particular type of object.

To participate nicely in this stack, you have to expect a request coming in and return a response back out.

> To pass the request deeper into the application (allowing the middleware to "pass"), simply call the $next callback with the $request.
>
> It's best to envision middleware as a series of "layers" HTTP requests must pass through before they hit your application. Each layer can examine the request and even reject it entirely.
>
> [Laravel Docs - Middleware - Defining Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#defining-middleware)